# Statistical calculation of value of coins in a box

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics

I woke up from a dream today that made me consider the following scenario:

A grocery store has an electronic donation box. Good Samaritans slide coins into the donation box, and the donation box calculates the sum value of the coins in the box by repeatedly grabbing five random coins and calculating the value of these five coins. The donation box does this five-coin-value calculation every second. Importantly, the donation box knows how many total coins are in the box.

**How many times would the donation box have to do its five-coin-value calculation to determine, with at least 95% accuracy, the value of all the coins in the box?**

I believe I would need to have some knowledge of discrete mathematics. Fortunately, I do, so I may be able to solve it. I would really love to tackle this question, but I need a pointing in the right direction, or an introduction.

Thanks a lot. I find the question very intriguing.

Comment: What assumptions do we make about the values of the coins that Good Samaritans are likely to donate? I mean, what are all the different possible values, and is a random person equally likely to donate any of them?

Comment: The coins are 1-cent, 5-cent, 10-cent and 25-cent. Each coin is equally likely. Thanks for the request for clarification.